# How can I add a legend that counts points above or below a certain value in ggplot2? Volcano Plot

Tags: ggplot2, colors, gradient, legend

I am trying to make a volcano plot (dot plot) where the points above a certain y value are colored in a gradient from red to green depending on their x value, and add a legend that specifies the number of points that are above these values.

I have a code similar to this one:

```
set.seed(123)
x <- runif(600, -3, 3)
y <- runif(600, 0, 0.6)
df<- as.data.frame(cbind(x,y))

df %>% ggplot(aes(x, -log10(y), color=x)) +
  geom_point()+
  geom_hline(yintercept=1.3, color="darkgrey")+
  scale_fill_gradient(low="red",high="green", aesthetics = "color")
```

Which (with my data) produces this plot:

[image]

But I want the legend to count the number of points which y>1.3 & x>0, and y>1.3 & x<0 separately (not to show the color bar) and I want the points below the line to be black.

Could someone help me?

Thanks!!!!

Comment: Welcome to SO. It would help if you made your question reproducible [reprex]. Could you include the data object `BSvsBC_volcano ` as a minimal `data frame` or `tibble` ? you can use `dput(BSvsBC_volcano )`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One point to note: legends in `ggplot` are only setup to explain how the aesthetics are represented.  In order for legends to display results or data (such as a tally of your information), you have to use a different approach from what is built in to `ggplot2`.

With that being said, here's an example using a subset of the diamonds dataset.

#### Data setup

Note I'm using a sample of the diamonds dataset because I'm lazy and did not want to wait for the 50000+ points of data to render.  :/

```
set.seed(12345)
di <- diamonds[sample(1:nrow(diamonds), 5000),]
```

I'm going to setup the plot to represent depth on the x axis and price on the y axis.  We will summarize the number of observations with high depth (> mean depth) and low depth (< mean depth), and which all have price > 6000.  We'll use this table later.

```
di.summary <- as.data.frame(
    di %>% dplyr::filter(price > 6000) %>%
    group_by(depth > mean(di$depth)) %>% tally()
)
chartTable <- cbind(c('Low\nDepth', 'High\nDepth'), di.summary[,2])
```

#### Basic Plot: Geom_point color setup

This illustrates the method that can be used for your chart to only change the color of certain points.  In this case, I want only points above 6000 in price to be colored, and all other points to be represented as gray dots.  The easiest way to do this is to have two `geom_point` calls and have them use different datasets.  One will have a color aesthetic applied (within `aes()`) and the other will have a gray color specified *outside* the `aes()` function.

```
p <- ggplot(di, aes(depth, price)) +
    geom_point(data=di[which(di$price > 6000),], aes(color=depth), size=1) +
    geom_point(data=di[which(di$price <= 6000),], color='gray80', size=1) +
    geom_hline(yintercept=6000) +
    geom_vline(xintercept=mean(di$depth), linetype=2) +
    scale_color_gradient(high='red', low='green')
p
```

[image]

#### Adding the Result table

In order to display the table in your plot, we are going to have to use a "grob" (short for "Graphics Object", I believe).  I'm going to convert the table using `tableGrob` from the `gridExtra` library.  You then pass that grob object to `annotation_custom()`, and specify the location within your chart.

One more point is that we are planning to put the table in the lower right corner *outside* the plot area (below the legend).  In order to do this, we need to make room for the table by adding a plot margin on the right.  We also need to turn clipping off so that the annotation can be represented outside the plot area.

```
library(gridExtra)

p +
  coord_cartesian(clip='off') +
  theme(
    plot.margin = margin(0,40,0,0)
  ) +
  annotation_custom(
    grob=tableGrob(chartTable, theme=ttheme_default(base_size = 9)),
    xmin=74.5, xmax=76, ymin=0, ymax=5000
  )
```

[image]

You can use a similar approach for your data.

#### Alternate Approach Using Text Annotations

An alternative approach to using a `tableGrob` could be to just represent the tally of points via text annotations.  I'll show an example of that here:

```
p +
    annotate(
        geom='label',
        x=min(di$depth), y=0.8*max(di$price),
        hjust=0,
        label=paste0('n=',di.summary[1,2])
    ) +
    annotate(
        geom='label',
        x=max(di$depth), y=0.8*max(di$price),
        hjust=1,
        label=paste0('n=',di.summary[2,2])
    )
```

[image]

While not your data, the above example should give you enough information to figure out how these can apply to your own data.

Comment: chemdork123 AMAZING. Thanks for the great code and explanations !!!